# JSP/Servlets - How to create conditons to fetch records from the database

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have below

1) StudentDAO.java ->  has a method to list all students

2) ListStudentServlet.java -> Contorller to get the list and send to jsp

3) ListStudent.jsp -> Display Student List

Now I want to add condtions such as

studentId greater than, less than, equals, etc
StudentName like '%A%
StudentDOB between date1 and date2

what's the best approach to get results based on above conditions. Do I need to creat separate methods for each of the condition or can i have one method with different where clauses?

Please can you an example?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can supply different GET parameters to the servlet. For example:

- `?operator=greaterThan&column=studentId&value=5`
- `?operator=like&column=name&value=%A`

You can also have these things coded in the servlet itself, and only submit one parameter that identifies the combination. For example, if you have a list of queries, you can have `?queryId=5`

Comment: sorry Bozho, i am new to jsp/servlet. How/where i need to put this code in JSP after getting response (list) from servlet? please can you give an example?